# preg replace, {{ only replace one

Tags: php, regex

Text-string:   {{ANREDE}}  Das ist ein Text

My regex:

```
 $Text = preg_replace('{{ANREDE}}', '<strong>Sehr geehrte Herr Muster</strong>', $Text);
```

Unfortunately it commes out like this {Sehr geehrte Herr Muster}

What is wrong?

Thanks for help

best regards
thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get output as:

`{<strong>Sehr geehrte Herr Muster</strong>} Das ist ein Text`

with one set of curly braces still left in output because outermost `{` and `}` acts as regex delimiter but leaving only one set of curly braces in your pattern.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
preg_replace('/{ANREDE}/', '<strong>Sehr geehrte Herr Muster</strong>', $Text);
```

However you don't even need a regex replacement here. You can just use `str_replace`:

```
$Text = str_replace('{{ANREDE}}', '<strong>Sehr geehrte Herr Muster</strong>', $Text);
```

**Output:**

```
<strong>Sehr geehrte Herr Muster</strong> Das ist ein Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the regex delimiters:

```
 $Text = preg_replace('/{{ANREDE}}/', '<strong>Sehr geehrte Herr Muster</strong>', $Text);
```

will come out as:

```
<strong>Sehr geehrte Herr Muster</strong> Das ist ein Text
```

Comment: Delimiters.  They are frequently NOT slashes.